# Twitter bootstrap navbar-inverse class doesn't make navbar inverse, and prevents links from appearing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hyperlink

I have built a simple webpage using Twitter Bootstrap, and I have 2 problems:

1. Although I have given the navbar a class of `navbar-inverse`, it just appears as a white rectangle and looks no different to the rest of the webpage. Divs with a class of `navbar-inverse` are supposed to have inverse colours: a dark `background-color`, and light text.
2. I have three links with an empty `href`, but they don't appear. They still don't appear if I give them a `href` of `#`.

Here is a link to the result I am getting: http://jsbin.com/poqofapiqa/edit?html,output

Comment: The `href` attribute requires a value. If you have none, you can use the *hashbang*, *.eg:* `href="#"`

Comment: This doesn't make any difference, as the hyperlinks are still not there. Also, I had the problem of the missing navbar _**before**_ I added the hyperlinks, and I still have that problem now that the hyperlnks have been added.

Comment: Ok, well your `.navbar-collapse` element will not appear because you are using the class `.collapse` - which is set to `display: none;`. There also appears to be no styles attributed `.navbar-inverse` and removing this calss makes no difference to the appearance of the element in question.

Comment: When I remove the `.collapse` class from the div, the hyperlinks reappear, but in the wrong place: in the top-right corner one on top of the other. See here:jsbin.com/jubelirodu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Navbars:

Use the navbar-dark and bg-dark classes instead:
`<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark"><!-- Navbar content --></nav>`

Links:

Use at least `<a href="#">...</a>` , not blank `href` attribute.
Anchors with blank attributes interpreted as usual (non-link) elements

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
 <style>
 
  .box {
   border:1px solid grey;
   background-color:#d3d3d3;
  }
 
 </style>
 
  </head>
  <body>
  
 <div class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
  
  <div class="container">
   
   <div class="navbar-header">
    
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Website</a>
    
   </div>
   
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     
     <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
     
    </ul>
    
   </div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div>
 
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
 
 <div class="container">
  
  <div class="row">
  
   <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
   
   <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
   
   <div class="col-md-4 box">Content</div>
   
  </div>
  
 </div> 
 
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That fixed the missing navbar, but when I hover over the hyperlink with '`My Website`' as it's content, nothing happens, and adding '#' to the href of the otehr hyperlinks doesn't help: they still don't appear. See here: http://jsbin.com/mujahigele/edit?html,output

Comment: @Aryan, please check my post again - I added the code snippet. In your last example, you haven't added the href="#" to "My Website" link

Comment: OK, the webpage with your advised edits added. See here: http://jsbin.com/fepoquwafa/edit?html,output

Comment: I noticed you had removed the `<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">` tag around your `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` element. Maybe you'd better try to copy this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/starter-template/ Bootstrap starter template?

Answer (score 0):

You are using it in a  wrong way. Class `nav-collapse` is used to display mobile menu button. The content available in `nav-collapse` will not be shown on webpage. 
You can use this code for your menu.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  

</body>
</html>
```